# How to turn off Nokia theme tune on startup?

Tags: boot, nokia-6

My Nokia 6 always made the Nokia theme tune when it was turned on from being completely off. However, for a short period, I had another user account on my phone and it didn't make the noise every time, but there were still a few instances where it did.

**I've Tried**

- Putting my phone in Do Not Disturb
- Using the Complete Silence DND option
- Having my phone on silent
- Aeroplane Mode
- Having my phone on charge and off charge makes no difference
- Looking for a setting that turns it off(suggested in a previous anwser)

All of these were done before I turned the phone completely off.

I've done some research on Nokia forums and other sites and most answers suggest one of the following above but none of the above have worked.

Now I have removed the other user and I am running the single user account with no guest user. It is making the noise more, but not every time as before I would say that it's roughly 40% of the time it makes the noise now.

Is the fact that I created the other user account linked to the noise stops, its the only thing I changed on my phone which is why I'm making that assumption.

Is there any way to stop the noise compleat as it can be annoying(and embarrassing) when turning my phone on in public?

I'm running Android 8.1.0

Comment: Have you tried plugging in headphones while restarting?

Comment: @DarkHippo Yes I have and the noise is still played through the speakers even with them plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Some Android phones allow going into Settings > Sound and finding a option called something along the lines of 'Startup Ringtone'.

Comment: Unfortunately, my phone doesn't have such a  setting, I'll edit that in my question for future answers

Answer (score 0):

Just place your finger over the speaker on the bottom of the phone on the right, it completely blocks the sound and only takes a second. I use this method every time and it works 100%.